# Check column exist or not if not exist assign null values for that column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have small question about SQL - when loading data from one table into another table I am facing an issue.

First table: `emp`

```
id | name | sal | deptno | loc  | referby
----------------------------------------
 1 | abc  | 100 |   10   | hyd  | xyz
 2 | mnc  | 200 |   20   | chen | pqr
```

Second table: `emprefers`

```
id | name | sal | deptno | loc | referby
```

Now I want load emp table data into emprefers table that time I write query like

```
insert into emprefers 
    select * 
    from emp
```

After running this query, data is loaded into emprefers like below:

```
id | name | sal | deptno | loc  |referby
----------------------------------------
 1 | abc  | 100 |   10   | hyd  | xyz
 2 | mnc  | 200 |   20   | chen | pqr
```

Now I ran the same query a second time, and it failed. Reason is name column is deleted from emp table

Now I edit the query like

```
insert into emprefers 
    select 
        id, 'null' as name, sal, deptno, loc, referby 
    from emp
```

After editing the query, I ran it - now records are loaded into the `emprefers` table and data looks like

```
id  | name  | sal | deptno | loc   | referby
--------------------------------------------
 1  | null  | 100 |   10   | hyd   | xyz
 2  | null  | 200 |   20   | chen  | pqr
```

Every time before loading emprefers table I truncate `emprefers` table data.
And `emprefers` table structure never changed.

Again, a third time I ran same query again query has failed reason for missing sal, deptno columns in emp table

Now I do not want to edit query again reason is we do not know which columns are deleted from emp table .that time we want solve the issue and we want load data into

Second table if the columns available in emp table then load data other wise we need to pass null or empty values for that columns.

Please tell me how to write query to check column exist or not if exist retrieve same column other wise assign null values for that column.

Comment: Do you know which columns may not exist and which will certainly exist? or you want the query to find that too?

Answer (score 0):

A quick work around is to use following query since your table structure doesn't change. If it changes, it will require more work.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N''

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns c WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'emp') AND c.name = 'id')
    SET @sql = @sql + ', id'

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns c WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'emp') AND c.name = 'name')
    SET @sql = @sql + ', name'

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns c WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'emp') AND c.name = 'sal')
    SET @sql = @sql + ', sal'

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns c WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'emp') AND c.name = 'deptno')
    SET @sql = @sql + ', deptno'

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns c WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'emp') AND c.name = 'loc')
    SET @sql = @sql + ', loc'

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns c WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'emp') AND c.name = 'referby')
    SET @sql = @sql + ', referby'

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO emprefers (' + STUFF(@sql, 1, 2, '') + ') SELECT * FROM emp'

PRINT @sql
EXEC(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cross Apply

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT NULL AS id,null as name,null as sal,null as deptno, null as loc,null as referby) AS dummy
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
   id,name,sal,deptno,loc,referby
  FROM dbo.emprefers
) AS x;
```

Have tested at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2e558/4

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe its a good idea doing such a thing since names might have changed keys might exists etc.
but this should do what you need:

```
Create Procedure P_Insert4ExisitingFields(@Source varchar(255),@Dest varchar(255)) as

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max)
-- collect all columns existing in both tables
Select @SQL = @SQL + '['+ a.name+'],' from
(
Select s.name from sys.syscolumns s
Join sysobjects m ON m.xtype ='U' and m.Name=@Source and s.id=m.ID
) a
JOIN
(
Select s.name from sys.syscolumns s
Join sysobjects m ON m.xtype ='U' and m.Name=@Dest and s.id=m.ID
) b on a.name=b.name 
--strip last ,
Select @SQL = SubString(@SQL,1,len(@SQL)-1)

Select @SQL = 'INSERT into [' + @Dest + '] ('+@SQL+') Select '+@SQL+' from [' + @Source +']'
--PRINT @SQL
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Example call would be :

```
P_Insert4ExisitingFields  'emp','emprefers'
```

assigning NULL values should not be necessary since this should be the default for the fields.